# Count of child record from JSON response in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need a count of child records from JSON response (GET API call) so I can store the value in variable and compare against database.

1. I have call GET API and got successful response

{"data":[{"id":"KbwnfXFA19WSErr6tt4CSkJP8","description":"Initial Consultation","siteId":"HC0115B","episodeTypeId":"N","episodeType":"Nursing Home","serviceCode":"C0000260","serviceCodeDescription":"Consultant"s Charge, Hearing Test","duration":30,"backgroundColour":"#E2FDFF","status":"A","includeInNewICESessions":false,"industryStandardCodeScheme":"ISC"},{"id":"XUbc2Gnz5cWx4G4vOECztGYJF","description":"fef2MFWpR5","siteId":"HC0115B","episodeTypeId":"I","episodeType":"Inpatient","serviceCode":"BC000325","serviceCodeDescription":"Familial Dysautonomia","duration":30,"backgroundColour":"#FF8FA3","status":"A","includeInNewICESessions":false,"industryStandardCodeScheme":"ISC"},{"id":"XUbc2Gnz5cWx4G4vOECztGYJF","description":"fef2MFWpR5","siteId":"HC0115B","episodeTypeId":"I","episodeType":"Inpatient","serviceCode":"BC000325","serviceCodeDescription":"Familial Dysautonomia","duration":30,"backgroundColour":"#FF8FA3","status":"A","includeInNewICESessions":false,"industryStandardCodeScheme":"ISC"}],"success":true,"errors":null,"statusCode":200}

Here I have got 3 records and I need to store count 3 in variable.

I need to validate against this count from against database count.

Answer (score 0):

What you provided isn't a valid JSON hence it won't be possible to go for [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor)

If you set Match Nr. to `-1` in the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) JMeter will generate an extra variable holding the number of matches.

[image]

In the above case it will generate 3 variables like:

```
records_1=foo
records_2=bar
records_3=baz
records_matchNr=3
```

So you will be able to compare this `${records_matchNr}` variable with the one holding count from the database.